# Properties of Digit root

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why the digit root of any number calculated in any way remains same...e.g

Let $f(x)$denote the digit root of $x$

$f(1237)=f(12+37)=f(49)=f(123+7)=f(130)=4$

I checked numerically with many numbers but I found that the digit root remains constant irrespective of the way the numbers are summed up I think it has something to do with modular math.A general proof would be appreciated

Comment: As written the left hand side would be 13. Did you mean $f(f(1237))$? In that case it is by definition.

Comment: @Sean Ballentine  the digit sum of $13$ will be $4$

Comment: Right, the digit sum of 1237 is 13. Then you want to apply $f$ again to get 4.

Comment: Oh I see, is the "digit root", $f$, defined to be the digit sum repeated. I thought $f$ was digit sum.

Comment: Sorry but you don't get me...

Comment: Note, *again*, that $f(1237) = 13.$ $\quad f(f(1237)) = 4$. And $f(49) = 13$... So it seems you may not "get you."

Comment: I have edited my question. $f(x)$ represents $digit root$ not digit sum..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally, this question was posted about $f$ being the "sum of digits" or the "digit sum". And it was answered accordingly.

To answer your original question: ... Because addition is associative, that's why.

---

Suppose we have a number with digits a, b, c, d, expressed as the concatenation $abcd$, in that order, and suppose we're defining "digit sum" to be $f(abcd) = a+b+c+d,$ and this will be the same digit sum of $a \cdot 10^3 + b\cdot 10^2 + c \cdot 10 + d$, or the digit sum of $(a \cdot 10 + b) + (c \cdot 10 + d)$, etc. We can then apply $f$ to $f(f(abcd))$, but again, addition is associative. We can apply $f$ repeatedly, and associatively, to arrive at the same "digit root" as you are calling it.

$$\begin{align} f(f(1237)) & = f(f(1 + 2 + 3 + 7)) \\ &= f(f(1+2) + f(3 + 7)) \\ &= f(f(f(1 + 2) + f(3)) + f(7)) \\ &= f(13) = 4 \\ & = \quad \cdots\end{align}$$

Comment: You're welcome, @TomLynd. Sometimes trying to figure out what we're trying to ask, or what we mean, can be more than half the battle. That's true for *all of us,* whether asking or answering!

Comment: Note that for the digit root, we have that $f(1237) \equiv 4 \pmod {9}$, and this is true for any combination $= f(12) \mod 4 + f(37) \mod 4$, e.g.

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear friend. :)

Comment: Hello, @Babak! ;-)